# I'm trying to include the Excel MDuration function into VBA code in an Access Module. Is this possible?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to include the Excel MDuration function into VBA code in an Access Module. Is this possible?

My goal is to calculate the Modified Duration of a bond using the key inputs and have the duration calculation sent to a table.

The code works up until the line "Duration = "=MDURATION(SettlementDate,MaturityDate,Coupon,Yield,Frequency)"

Where I'm I going wrong or is this simply not possible?

My code is as follows.

```
Public Function CalcDuration()

Dim SettlementDate As Date
Dim MaturityDate As Date
Dim Coupon As Double
Dim Yield As Double
Dim Duration As Double
Dim Frequency As Double


SettlementDate = InputBox("Enter Settlement Date ", "Enter Value")
MaturityDate = InputBox("Enter Maturity Date ", "Enter Value")
Coupon = InputBox("Enter Coupon ", "Enter Value")
Yield = InputBox("Enter Yield ", "Enter Value")
Frequency = InputBox("Enter Frequency ", "Enter Value")
Duration = "=MDURATION(SettlementDate,MaturityDate,Coupon,Yield,Frequency)"


CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Duration" _
    & "(SettlementDate, Duration) VALUES " _
    & "(#" & SettlementDate & "#, " & Duration & ")"



End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you've selected "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library" in Tools | References

Next, you need to add a few things to your code:
Add this to the top lines: 
    Dim xl as Object
    Set xl=CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Change this line as follows:
    Duration = xl.MDuration(SettlementDate, MaturityDate, Coupon, Yield,
        Frequency)

Here's the quick and dirty code:
    Public Function CalcDuration()

```
Dim xl As Object
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim SettlementDate As Date
Dim MaturityDate As Date
Dim Coupon As Double
Dim Yield As Double
Dim Duration As Double
Dim Frequency As Double

SettlementDate = InputBox("Enter Settlement Date ", "Enter Value")
MaturityDate = InputBox("Enter Maturity Date ", "Enter Value")
Coupon = InputBox("Enter Coupon ", "Enter Value")
Yield = InputBox("Enter Yield ", "Enter Value")
Frequency = InputBox("Enter Frequency ", "Enter Value")
Duration = xl.MDuration(SettlementDate, MaturityDate, Coupon, Yield, 
    Frequency)

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Duration" _
& "(SettlementDate, Duration) VALUES " _
& "(#" & SettlementDate & "#, " & Duration & ")"

End Function
```